# HUE Workflow Failed: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.Hive2Main], exit code [2]

Tags: hive, oozie, hue

I am using HUE and created a test workflow. I created a simple saved query and added it to the workflow as a document. When I run it, it always gets killed with the error `Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.Hive2Main], exit code [2]`. Why is this occurring?

Comment: You would probably need to look at the logs of the MapReduce action of the Oozie job itself (or Oozie itself). Most of the time it is a misconfiguration of the hive-site.xml or Oozie sharelib.

Comment: Do you mean the log of the task? When I try to click on it it says 'Could not find job application_xxx.' When I go to the console url, it shows no errors, but I don't have permission to access to log there it says because I am logged in as 'dr.who'.